# How to convert Mat object to tensorflow Tensor in RUST Language?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, opencv, rust, opencv3.0

this is my opencv code, how to convert padded_f32 mat object to tensorflow Tensor ?

```
let image = imgcodecs::imread("image_2021_08_02T09_11_01_447Z.png", imgcodecs::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE).unwrap();

let mut resized_image = Mat::default();
imgproc::resize(&image, &mut resized_image, Size::new(320, 320), 3., 3., 0);

let mut rgb_image = Mat::default();
imgproc::cvt_color(&resized_image, &mut rgb_image, imgproc::COLOR_BGR2RGB, 0)?;

let mut padded_f32 = Mat::default();
rgb_image.convert_to(&mut padded_f32, f32::typ(), 1., 0.)?;
```